# Can MSDeploy Parameter files be stored and accessed on target server?

Tags: msdeploy, automated-deploy

Is it possible to have your parameter files for msdeploy stored and accessed from the target server, or does information for each server have to be kept on the machine that you are publishing from?  I am setting up automated builds and hoping to be able to deploy to multiple servers.  It would be nice if the parameter file could be kept on the target server for the connection string changes since that information is already on the machine in the Web.config and I wouldn't have to store them all on the build server or in source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this today. Can you explain more what you are trying to acheive?